# Operações aritméticas no PHP ou no MySQL?

Tags: banco-de-dados, laravel, desempenho, operadores

Qual seria a boa pratica na hora de fazer operações aritméticas que venham de uma consulta de banco de dados, por exemplo:

```
SELECT 
    valor_bruto_atual,
    valor_investido,
    (valor_bruto_atual / valor_investido) AS rendimento,
    (valor_bruto_atual - valor_investido) AS rendimento_liquido
FROM
    ativos_extratos;
```

Nesse exemplo eu apenas retorno 2 colunas e 2 cálculos (divisão e subtração)

Nesse próximo exemplo com uso do model do Laravel fiz um foreach percorrendo a mesma consulta *(sem os cálculos)*.

```
echo "<pre>";
foreach($ativos->get() as $ativo){
    echo $ativo->valor_bruto_atual;
    echo $ativo->valor_investido;
    echo $ativo->valor_bruto_atual / $ativo->valor_investido;
    echo $ativo->valor_bruto_atual - $ativo->valor_investido;            
}
echo "</pre>";
dd('stop');
```

*O PHP é apenas ilustrativo, mesmo em meu ambiente de teste esse exemplo sendo totalmente funcional.*

Agora vem a real pergunta, qual seria a melhor forma de se fazer esses cálculos, no próprio MySQL ou deixar para o PHP faze-lo?

Qual seria a boa pratica pra tal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via de regra é melhor manter no banco de dados. Se fizer no servidor de aplicação (PHP) tem o overhead de transferir uma quantidade de dados que pode ser grande para só depois fazer o cálculo, que o próprio banco de dados é capaz de gerenciar ao processar sua consulta.

É duro chamar isso de boa prática, termo que já foi tantas vezes desaprovado aqui no SOpt, mas acredito que essa questão do overhead em geral tem que ser considerada.

O @LucasProchnow levantou um ponto que é escalar o banco (acredito que nesse momento cabem otimizações seja nas consultas ou na aplicação) e acabou esbarrando em um ponto importante, que é o custo de manutenção desse código. Eu só pensei no volume de dados. Ele está certo, é uma escolha mesmo.

Answer (score 3):

Na minha opinião, é melhor fazer esses cálculos a nível de máquina, ou seja, no PHP.

Com poucos dados esses cálculos não farão diferença na performance e nem no custo ($$) para manter o DB, mas conforme os dados vão aumentando, esses cálculos vão ser bem custosos a nível de DB. Resumindo, é muito mais barato e fácil você escalar uma máquina de aplicação do que de banco.

Mas como eu disse, é a minha opinião. Acho que esse caso não existe certo/errado, existe uma escolha (;

O @Piovezan levantou outro ponto importante sobre overhead, só reforça que é uma questão de escolha